# Problems using mysql

Tags: 13.04, mysql, lamp

I just opened mysql by typing "mysql" in the terminal.
Then, I went to create a database which threw this error :-

```
mysql> create database test2;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'test2'
mysql>
```

How do I fix this ?
P.S - I've installed LAMP using tasksel.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Start MySQL as root, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, MySQL is a database *server*. That means, you need a client to connect to a MySQL server. The `mysql` command line program you are using is such a client.

As with many systems, a MySQL server has its own user accounts and privileges. So if you connect a client to a MySQL server, you have to provide an username and (almost always) a password. If you don't provide the `mysql` with an username, it assumes you want to use the UNIX/Linux username you are logged into your server as. For example, if you are logged into your server as 'joe', `mysql` tries to use the MySQL user of the same name, which is 'joe@localhost'. As you see, MySQL user accounts always contain the hostname you are connecting from. That is automatically added.

If you want to connect to your MySQL server as the user 'joe@localhost', you can do

```
mysql -u joe
```

With this, MySQL assumes that the MySQL server is running on the same machine as the client (therefore, the 'localhost' hostname is automatically added) and 'joe@localhost' does not have a password set.

If the desired MySQL user account *has* a password set, you can have the `mysql` client ask for it with

```
mysql -u joe -p
```

And, for the sake of completeness, if you want to connect to a MySQL on another machine as the client runs on, you can do something like

```
mysql -h my-mysql-server.com -u joe -p
```

In your special case, the MySQL user account the `mysql` client connects to the MySQL server as does not have the necessary privileges to create a new database. You need to connect as a MySQL user that has these privileges. Which user account that is depends on how you set the MySQL server up.